# what ever the data i am giving in textarea same format data i am not getting in browser

Tags: angular

For example i have given data in text area like

"Dear Sir,

My name Samir"
format data but i am getting in one line "Dear Sir, My name samir"
output should:
"Dear Sir,

My name Samir"
so i want output  (what ever the format user will give in text area i want same format in the browser)

app.component.ts

```
    public textarea:string;
    public value:string;
    mydata()
    {
     this.value=this.textarea;
    }
```

app.component.html

```
    <div>
    <textarea id="sfgh" name="w3review" rows="4" cols="50" [(ngModel)]="textarea">

     </textarea>
    </div>
     <button (click)="mydata()">CLICK</button>
    <div>
     <span>{{value}}</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: <pre>{{value}}</pre>

Answer (score 2):

This is a CSS concern, make sure to add `white-space: pre-line` to the desired element.

Further read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, whitespace is largely ignored — whitespace in between words is treated as a single character, and whitespace at the start and end of elements and outside elements is ignored [whitespaces in html](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Whitespace).

You can use the tag `<pre></pre>` to display preformatted text. [`<pre>` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre)